# Cannot cast form Fragment to Mapfragment

Tags: android

i Want to make maps in android, this is for My Skripsi, i Download Source code in here https://github.com/ajaswal/GoogleMapsV2 i strat open project, but have proble this is my problem, i have alert about cannot cast from Fragment to MapFragment, this problem in line 27.

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

so please help me...

```
package com.example.googlemaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public final LatLng LOCATION_BURNABY= new LatLng(49.27645, -122.917587);
public final LatLng LOCATION_SURREY= new LatLng(49.187500, -122.849000);

private GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (map != null) {
        setUpMap();
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    // Enable MyLocation layer of Google map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Get Location manager object from System service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Get the name of the best provider

            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Get current location
            Location myLocation = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            // Set map type
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            // Get the latitude of the current location
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

            // Get the longitude of the current location
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng LOCATION_CURRENT = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Show the current location in Google map
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LOCATION_CURRENT));

            // Zoom in the google map
            CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    LOCATION_CURRENT, 15);
            map.animateCamera(camUpdate);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick_Burnaby(View v){
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_BURNABY, 13);
    map.animateCamera(update);
}

public void onClick_Surrey(View v){
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_SURREY, 14);
    map.animateCamera(update);
}}
```

Comment: Show your XMl file. Also extends your class with `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-google-maps-api-v2-example.html

Comment: post your xml and have u added `google-play-service_lib` as a library in ur project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) instead of Activity

Example -

```
public class MapScreen extends FragmentActivity{

    private GoogleMap map;
    private Location location;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> mLocationsLatLngList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map_screen);


        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment)).getMap();
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(Your_CurrentLocation).zoom(13).bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(30)    // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();    // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));   

    }   
}
```

xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have a look Open map on Activity Not On FragmentActivity  http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-google-maps-api-v2-example.html

Comment: Hey 1 suggasion if u raise your reputation on stackppverflow dont answers all questions just answers valuable answer which you earned more and if you really help to people than provide this type of answers in comment. not as a sepreat answers

Comment: do u know when to use `SupportMapFragment` and when `MapFragment` what about this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Comment: @kaushik No..I was also getting this kind of error.and after searching a lot found this solution..and its working so I posted it.

Comment: Check android developer doc - http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html and google doc - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/SupportMapFragment

Comment: `SupportMapFragment` is used for pre-honeycomb versions. If in ur app's *minSdkVersion* is `12` then `MapFragment` is used. But it is better to use `SupportMapFragment` for backward compatibility from `2.2` api-8. But here it is not what op want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `SupportMapFragment` in the `XML`, so you must use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`.

Use this code to obtain the `Fragment` and the `Map`:

```
SupportMapFragment fr = (SupportMapFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
GoogleMap Map = fr.getMap();
```

Your `Activity` must extend `FragmentActivity`.